# how to get the values of one array of objects key based on values of another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

```
   data = {
{'uid': 12, 'amount': 100},
{'uid': 23, 'amount': 250}
}
object = {12:{'name':'Paul', 'id':12}, 20:{'name':'Mike', 'id':20}, 41:{'name':'Jack', 'id':41}, 23:{'name':'Luke', 'id':23}}
```

the output expected is

```
const result = {{'name':'Paul', 'id': 12, 'amount':100}, {'name':'Luke', 'id': 12, 'amount': 250}}
```

I tried mapping the uids to get and array of values like

```
uids = [12, 23]
```

then

```
        names = uids.map(key => object[key].name);
```

so that I could use them to map the keys and the names in the other object but couldn't figure it out
I know it is basic javascript but I am new to this

Comment: now your result is invalid, because every nested object needs a key.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply map the object with the given keys.

```js
var array = [12, 23],
    object = { 12: { name: 'Paul', id: 12 }, 20: { name: 'Mike', id: 20 }, 41: { name: 'Jack', id: 41 }, 23: { name: 'Luke', id: 23 } },
    result = array.map(key => object[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nina that dis the trick... I actually gotta update my question that was the head of the iceberg :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
{'uid': 12, 'amount': 100},
{'uid': 23, 'amount': 250}
};

var object = {12:{'name':'Paul', 'id':12}, 20:{'name':'Mike', 'id':20}, 41:{'name':'Jack', 'id':41}, 23:{'name':'Luke', 'id':23}};

var uids = [12, 23];

    mappedValues = uids.map(key => object[key]);

 var result = mappedValues.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, data[i]));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the structure of `data` is wrong. It should be an array. Then you could do this:

```js
   data = [
{'uid': 12, 'amount': 100},
{'uid': 23, 'amount': 250}
];


object = {12:{'name':'Paul', 'id':12}, 20:{'name':'Mike', 'id':20}, 41:{'name':'Jack', 'id':41}, 23:{'name':'Luke', 'id':23}};

for(let key in object){
  var match = data.filter(i=>i.uid.toString() === key);
  if(match && match.length){
    object[key].amount = match[0].amount;
  }
}
console.log(object)
```